# Calculating TOA reflectance from Radiance using Erdas Imagine for a Spot2 image

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, spot5, model-maker

Using the SPOT equation   ρ = π L/[E cos (θs) d-²] to calculate TOA reflectance from Radiance.

L was calculated using this equation [L = (X/A) + B]

d was calculated by converting date to julian day then converting to d using http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/Landsat_Calibration_Summary_RSE.pdf

Esun  was calculated using http://www2.astrium-geo.com/files/pmedia/public/r452_9_normalsolarirradiance.pdf

To calculate cos (θs), taking the sun elevation from 90 and then converting to radians http://www.mathinary.com/degrees_radians.jsp  and then getting the cos of the answer

Example of above equation filled in for a Spot2 image p= (3.14*radian band1)/(1865*(0.98717*0.98717)*cos(70))

This equation works in Erdas Model maker however the resulting image is blank.

I need to know where I'm going wrong using the equation in Erdas

Comment: not sure, but I think Erdas work with radians

Comment: that'd be my first question: are you using the correct angle units?

Comment: @martinf converted to radians still having the same problem

Comment: It's not my specialty but I'd suggest providing more details of your equation: a link, descriptions of d, L, etc, and values that seem correct. Other folks should then have more to go on, to help.

Comment: L was cal using this equation [L = (X/A) + B]. Esun using http://www2.astrium-geo.com/files/pmedia/public/r452_9_normalsolarirradiance.pdf      d was cal by converting date to julian day then converting using http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/Landsat_Calibration_Summary_RSE.pdf                                             cos (θs) by taking the sun elevation from 90 and then converting to radians http://www.mathinary.com/degrees_radians.jsp and then getting the cos of the answer

Comment: Example of above equation filled in for a Spot2 image  p= (3.14*radian band1)/(1865*(0.98717*0.98717)*cos(70)) This equation works in Erdas Model maker however the resulting image is blank.

Comment: Great. Now please [edit] all that into the question so that it stands alone as a complete cohesive question. (Comments can easily be deleted, questions should endure.)